# I have no clue in programming... Help needed in Kohana

Tags: kohana

A developer worked on a website for us where we can upload images. Everytime I try I get this error message. But not with all images. Some images are uploaded but do not appear. Am I missing something?

```
"Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory DOCROOT/data/clients/logos/ must be writable"

**SYSPATH/classes/kohana/upload.php [ 80 ]**

75    $directory = Upload::$default_directory;
76    }
77 
78    if ( ! is_dir($directory) OR ! is_writable(realpath($directory)))
79    {
80    throw new Kohana_Exception('Directory :dir must be writable',
81    array(':dir' => Debug::path($directory)));
82    }
83 
84    // Make the filename into a complete path
85    $filename = realpath($directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;
```

Answer (score 2):

DOCROOT is the root path of your kohana application. I normally contains the following folders and files:

```
application/
modules/
system/
index.php
```

In your case there is also an `data` folder. The easiest way to fix your problem is to first check if all folders exist. Do the following from the root path:

```
cd data/clients/logos/
```

if it throws an error do the following commands

```
mkdir data/clients/logos
chmod 777 data/clients/logos
```

if you don't get an error do the following commands

```
cd ../
chmod 777 logos
```

I'm flying blind here so I could be wrong but this should fix your upload issues

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory `DOCROOT/data/clients/logos/` exists and is writeable. `DOCROOT` is most likely a configuration variable somewhere and should be the folder from where the webserver serves its files.

Comment: Thanks for that... But I am not developer whatsoever, and have no clue what I should be doing. So... I am assuming I need to create a folder called DOCROOT, and within that folder create another folder called data, and within that create another folder called clients, and then another folder within that called logos?

Comment: Does the image file type matter?

Comment: Ok... so I just did that, but it didnt help still same error message. As I explained above, it works with some images, usually larger sized images but when it uploads it only shows an "x" where the image should be.

Comment: Still hoping someone can answer me... Thanks